# Can I set a variable scoped to a perspective?

Tags: projectile, dynamic-scoping, persp-mode

I have a large monorepo repository and open different parts of it in a persp-mode perspective. It would be nice if *for all buffers owned by that perspective* I could set for example `projectile-project-root`. Is this possible?

Side note (not part of the official question, maybe just add a comment?) Is there a good rundown on how exactly scope works in elisp other than [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Scoping.html) - they're helpful but pretty bare bones and not really enough for me to grok fully how this works especially when plugins are in the equation.

Comment: Maybe you can use directory local variables https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html

Comment: @JohnKitchin but first of all, `projectile-project-root` is buffer-local (and I'm not sure like I said how scoping works there). But more importantly, if I visit that file in a different perspective I do *not* want it to shift projects for me. The use case is that I have a monorepo and need to retain the ability to jump around it while at the same time being able to focus on a couple areas in a different perspective.